# Не отправляться форма

Tags: html, php

собственно не могу получить пост  в скрипт
вот форма

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" cols="100" rows="20" required form="text" ></textarea>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
            </script>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" form = "form1" ></p>
        </form>
```

Вот скрипт 
    <?php

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'xxxxxx';

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'brtcvu4');
if (!$link) {
    die('wrong: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'right';

mysql_select_db ('test', $link) or die (mysql_error());

$title = $_POST['title'];
$m_pst = $_POST['form1'];
$trys =$_POST['editor1'];

echo($_POST);
echo($m_pst);
echo($trys);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test.posts ( nam , post ) VALUES ('$trys','$m_pst')") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_close($link);
```

как видите пробовал и так и так. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь получить 
$title = $_POST['title'];
$m_pst = $_POST['form1'];
$trys =$_POST['editor1'];

1. Где, простите в форме инпут с именем Title ?
2. Зачем Вы передаете саму форму (Form1) ? форму вы никак не передадите и уж тем более не внесете в БД.

Единственный POST для передачи это editor1. Его и пробуйте вывести через Echo. Если выводится значит все работает.

И я не совсем понял, назначение этого скрипта
<script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
            </script>